# Log Squared Return

Tags: logarithms

I have to calculate the return of a portfolio. Suppose it is

$P=100*r_{1}$

I have been suggested to take the log of the return, such that $log(P)=log (100*r_{1})$.

But if the argument of the log is <0, I cannot do it.

Does it makes sense to take squared of the argument?

Comment: Is $P<0$ ? …...

Comment: yes, if i have a bad return and r<0 then P<0

Comment: If $r<0$ take $log(-P)=log(100*(-r))$. You also can use the absolute value in your equation.

Comment: yes, now it works, but does it make sense according to a "financial point of view?"

Comment: This is a matter of financial model. Ask Financiers. If they can prove that $log(P)=log(100*r)$ in case of $r>0$ on the same manner they might prouve  that $log(-P)=log(-100*r)$ in case of $r<0$.

Comment: Find where the financial model $log(P)=log(100*r)$ comes from and how this equation is stated in case of $r>0$. Proceed on the same manner to model the case $r<0$.